# Crystal Report Operation could not be completed class not registered

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Whenever I try to add new item --> Crystal report, it first pops **invalid keycode**  and when i click ok it says **Operation could not be completed class not registered**. What can be the possible issue? I have referenced all the dlls.
And yes this issue is only found when i opern crystal reports in visual studio, if I open it individually from start menu, the report is opened correctly.

[image]

Comment: I'm posting this question again because I can't find solution in the question asked previously.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Im getting the same error.